# Error on project and redLine on VS on the code where not a mistake. Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My problem is in start debug. When I build the project it is ok. But when I start debug I have a proble with misstake where is not misstake. It is on method OnCreate(). I get this project from svn server. Cod below and error you will see on scrinshot

[image]

[image]

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        UserDialogs.Init(this);
        Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        InitLibraries();

        LoadApplication(new App());

        OnNewIntent(Intent);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Intent?.Data?.LastPathSegment))
        {
            switch (Intent?.Data?.LastPathSegment)
            {
                case "Search":
                    Console.WriteLine("Search");
                    ShortcutsManager.GoToSearch();
                    break;
                case "OnExecution":
                    Console.WriteLine("On execution documents");
                    ShortcutsManager.GoToOnExecution();
                    break;
                case "InWork":
                    Console.WriteLine("In work documents");
                    ShortcutsManager.GoToInWork();
                    break;
                case "Calendar":
                    Console.WriteLine("Calendar");
                    ShortcutsManager.GoToCalendar();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

And the same situation in the same file with other methods. For example

```
 public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        Page currentPage = GetCurrentPage();

        if (currentPage is LoginPage)
            MoveTaskToBack(true);
        else if (PopupNavigation.PopupStack.Count > 0)
            base.OnBackPressed();
        else if (currentPage is MainMasterDetailPage)
            if ((currentPage as MainMasterDetailPage).Master is FolderMenuPage)
                OnDoubleBackToPressed();
            else
                base.OnBackPressed();
    }
```

The eror is "missing reference" but all references are on project

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Application' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Clean the project, delete bin/obj folders and try to build again.

Comment: in adroid project delet??

Comment: sorry, didn`t help

Comment: @FX_Sektor,You can delete bin and obj in Android and Forms project, rebuilding project, if there are still some issue, please upload your project in github and share the link here, I will try it at my side

Comment: You may want to try to update Xamarin.Forms via Nuget manager